# I need one regular expression which matches multiple conditions

Tags: regex, validation

I need one regular expression which matches multiple conditions.

1. Total length of input must be less than or equal to 5 characters
2. If input starts with "0" it must have * or "-" inside it.
3. If input does not start with "0" it can have any characters with total length less than or equal to 5 characters.

```
01234   ->Invalid(No * or -)
0*234   ->Valid
0*2345  ->Invalid (more than 5 characters)
012-    ->Valid
 12345   ->Valid
#456   ->Valid   
123456  ->Invalid (more than 5 characters)
```

Comment: Why you failed to count spaces as chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead based regex.

```
^(?=.{1,5}$)(?:0.*[*-]|[^0]).*$
```

*or*

If you don't want to count for spaces.

```
^(?=(?:\s*\S){1,5}\s*$)(?:0.*[*-]|[^0]).*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iD8nZ8/1)

Comment: I don't think that the given regexp will work properly.  It is just what I was typing up and then saw your post.  Correct me if I am wrong.  I am human after all, but the question wasn't "0" and then "\*" or "-" - it was that the "\*" and "-" has to appear SOMEWHERE in the string.  So it could be 0*000, 00*00,000*0 or 0000*. Or the same with the dash.  Also, he doesn't say if you can have both in there. Assuming only one but just saying....

Comment: `it was that the "" and "-" has to appear SOMEWHERE in the string`, ya.. did you check with `0foo*`

Comment: Eh?  I just figured out you have to use the backslash in front of the asterik/star.  Otherwise SO takes it out.  Can you edit your reply and tell me what 0foo means?  Nevermind - just got it.  Thanks! :-)